# Angular, animation does not work server

Tags: angular, animation

I did animation in my app it displaying ok in my local but not working server. I deployed my app on heroku. I am not understand where the problem in server why animation not working. Any idea? I need help on this issue.

Comment: Have you checked the developer console within the browser when running on the server?

Comment: Could you provide the link to the heroku deployment?

Comment: @ Code Ratchet, Yes it is working chrome but not working safari.

Comment: Ok and do you get any errors in the safari developer console?

Comment: This Error "Found the synthetic property fadeIn. Please include either "BrowserAnimationsModule" or "NoopAnimationsModule" in your application." 

But I have already BrowserAnimationsModule.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```

Import BrowserAnimationsModule, which introduces the animation capabilities into your Angular root application module.